# Performance issue with SQL Server and XML datatype columns

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2016, sqlperformance, shred

I am encountering performance issues using an XML datatype column in SQL Server 2016. It looks like my query is looping through the xml over and over. Here is my setup:

- Create a table with an ID int column (PrimaryKey) and an XML column
  `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MYTABLE]([ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,[XMLDATA] [xml] NULL,CONSTRAINT [PK_MYTABLE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]`
- Import around 3,000 xml files (~200KB in size) which look something similar to this:
  `<root>
  <item>
  <transaction>
  <prop1></prop1>
  <prop2></prop2>
  </transaction>
  <load>
  <loaditem>
  <loadprop1></loadprop1>
  <loadprop2>
  <loadsubprop1></loadsubprop1>
  </loadprop2>
  </loaditem>
  </load>
  </item>
  </root>`
  where there can be 400 to 500 "loaditems".
- I added 2 indexes using [this article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/precision-indexing-basics-of-selective-xml-indexes-in-sql-server-2012/)
- I create views to retrieve the xml as tabular data and I've tried both the .query() and the .nodes/.value method.

Performance of a simple query over a total of 3300 records is dreadful; it takes 45 seconds to query just the transaction/prop1  and prop2 part...

Comment: from what type of query do you speak ? a select? an insert?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my queries performed MUCH better without the indexes. I removed them and instead of 45 seconds it's down to 2 seconds...